# How do I keep a VBScript Message Box Centered?

Tags: vbscript, message, messagebox

I'm starting to learn VBScript but what I can't find is a tutorial on how to make a message box centered. I want to make the message box centered even if the person opening the file tries to move it. I hope someone replies! Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do that with the built in VBScript/WSH msgboxes, which is a good thing as it would be incredibly annoying.

Comment: A custom dialog using an `InternetExplorer.Application` object might be possible, but that would be an entirely different question. And it would still be *incredibly* annoying.

Comment: Like  the others said... thank god this is not possible.

Comment: If you find that annoying, try going on hurr durr on Internet Explorer...